# Rails 4: JSON::GeneratorError: NaN not allowed in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am getting the following error when making an ajax request to a controller in my Rails 4.2.11 app:

```
F, [2019-06-06T14:03:03.512611 #77610] FATAL -- :
JSON::GeneratorError - 865: NaN not allowed in JSON:
```

And I've identified the source of the error: a `float` field (or `double` in the database) that Rails has stored as `NaN`, which is not being converted to the string version, `'NaN'`, in order for it to be considered valid JSON:

```
{
  "id" => 123,
  "position" => NaN
}
```

I saw that this problem was supposedly fixed (see [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26933) and [this Rails commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2e421ad3df9918261a81f8dd602552685882f75e)). However, the problem seems to still be present with my version of Rails. Any idea how I can solve it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How about turning the field into a string before converting it to json?

Comment: I could iterate over all the object's attributes and convert them to strings, yes, but I'd rather Rails' `.to_json` method actually worked as expected. Simply converting everything to a string might have unintended consequences.